# Convert BASE64 to PDF Viewer

Tags: vb.net

How do I convert base64 string to be viewable in a vb.net application? I have found a few ways to convert the base64 string to create a PDF file, but seemed to have an issue with AxAcroPDFLib control.

The below code will load the test.pdf only if I create a new standalone project. When I try to load test.pdf in my current live project the AxAcroPDFlib (PDF Viewer) will not load anything. Seems like it cannot find the file to load. Everything is identical in the two projects though. Almost seems like the dll is corrupt somehow.

```
    Dim str As String = base64Code
    Dim Base64Byte() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(str)
    Dim obj As FileStream = File.Create("C:\users\steve\desktop\test.pdf")
    obj.Write(Base64Byte, 0, Base64Byte.Length)
    pdfPremViewer.LoadFile("C:\users\steve\desktop\test.pdf")
    obj.Flush()
    obj.Close()
```

Just to test loading a sample file into the viewer I have tried the below code and still doesn't even load a standard pdf file... Seems like the issue is with the viewer itself. (as mentioned above, works fine on a standalone new project).

```
    pdfPremViewer.src = "C:\users\steve\desktop\test.pdf"
    pdfPremViewer.LoadFile("C:\users\steve\desktop\test.pdf")
```

I am open to using a different method than AxAcroPDFlib as well.

Comment: Have you even looked for this answer before posting it here?

Comment: @roryap Yes i have

Comment: Have you read [ask] yet? How about [mcve]?

Comment: Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(strModified)            

    strOriginal = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b) - 4th link searching google. http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/convert-string-to-base64-and-base64-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not use the AxAcroPDFlib reference because of the above issues. I chose with just passing the files this way.

```
        Dim adobeReaderPath As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(adobeReaderPath, Base64ToPDF(getBase64Data(_sql)))
```